# Vault wrapping token - number of usage

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We are facing issue with fetching secrets from Hashicorp Vaullt. Client is actually using role_id and secret_id to auth in Vault. We also use wrapping function for secret_id, so once secret_id is fetched from Vault, it's wrapped and has to be unwrapped to get real secret_id.
Now problem is that wrapping token obtained from Vault has number of usage 1. Meaning that secret_id can be unwrapped only once. When we try 2nd time to unwrap, it is failing. And reason is number of usace for such generated token which is 1 by default.

```
Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            LctZYfQyzJVleDb41l7mACu5
creation_time       1603924396
creation_ttl        240h
display_name        n/a
entity_id           n/a
expire_time         2020-11-07T22:33:16.378745728Z
explicit_max_ttl    240h
id                  s.ajjvwjfjtTedj7xaeGW1B1WL
issue_time          2020-10-28T22:33:16.378758503Z
meta                <nil>
num_uses            1
orphan              true
path                auth/approle/role/img/secret-id
policies            [response-wrapping]
renewable           false
ttl                 239h58m30s
type                service
```

This is making a lot of issues for us. Is there a way to increase, or set as unlimited number od wrap token usage?

Thank you!

Comment: You could unwrap it once to obtain the real secret_id, then reuse that secret_id directly

Comment: Our use case is that we keep wrap token in config file, and each time app is restarted it is going to read config file, use wrap token to unwrap secret_id... But this is not possible because of this limitation - it's possible to do unwrap only once. And this makes wrap functionality useless for us. We do not want app to take care of saving secret_id all the way along. Once the app is restarted , it's releasing memory actually and it's not possible secret_id to survive app restart in memory. Any workaround  for this? Any possibility to set 'num_uses' diff then 1?

Answer (score 3):

The point of wrapping is that it is only unwrappable once. If you want a token that allows access to a secret for an extended period, then you want a 'regular' token. So create a policy that allows access only to the `secret_id`, create a new token with only that policy attached, and store that token. Now you have a token that you can use to request the `secret_id` secret from Vault.